# Why and how do systems of particles "forget" the initial conditions after some time has passed?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I am currently studying statistical mechanics, and am reading David Tong's notes on the subject.

In his first section, he remarks the following:

> We will only discuss systems that have been left alone for some time. This ensures that the energy and momentum in the system has been redistributed among the many particles and any memory of whatever special initial conditions the system started in has long been lost. Operationally, this means that the probability distribution is independent of time which ensures that the expectation values of the macroscopic observables are also time independent.

I've heard a similar argument in lecture applied to particles in an ideal gas, explaining why this leads to the reasonable assumption that the direction of motion can be treated as random.

My question is, what is the precise mechanism of this "redistribution"? Why can we assume that everything gets redistributed evenly? What is stopping a single particle, say, from "stealing" all of the energy for itself when the system has been left to its own devices? I have some intuition that such a state is obviously unlikely, but I am looking for a more mathematically convincing argument, or at least a more precise notion of what's really going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible for a single particle to steal all the energy, just like it is possible for all the air to be on one side of the room. It is just so unlikely that it would not come close to happening if the universe had been filled with rooms since the Big Bang.

It is always possible for a room to start off in an unlikely configuration such as all the energy in one particle. If you let such a system go, it would (almost certainly) flow to one of the many normal configurations. All of these look alike - energy distributed among all the particles more or less evenly in the usual distribution. Air spread evenly throughout the room.

The way information is lost is by not keeping track of the details. In a classical world, you could theoretically track all the trajectories. You could theoretically work backwards to the initial condition.

But you can't if you only keep track of the summary of the picture. Things like temperature and pressure being uniform over the room.

Answer (score 2):

It is not particularly difficult to see why this would be the case: each particle, with its various different degrees of freedom, can have various configurations of energy states. When that particle interacts with other particles, the energy will be re-distributed both within the molecule’s degrees of freedom and between other those of molecules in an extremely complicated way. Over time, as this process repeats many times, our ability to distinguish what the system “originally looked like” is completely and utterly lost in all the noise of these various interactions. This manifests in the autocorrelation function for the states of the system decaying over time until there is effectively no manifest connection between the state it adopts and its initial state.

To your second question about what stops this hypothetical unlikely state from happening, nothing at all! In fact, the ergodic hypothesis suggests that if we wait long enough that we actually will sample this state at some point. The thing working against you is entropy. If we take the system of interest to be isolated, then the second law states that we will, on average, always move towards states of higher entropy as the system evolves toward equilibrium. That is to say, more probable and high multiplicity states will tend to be occupied by pure statistical likelihood. This process is also reflected in a microscopic analysis of the re-distribution of energy. Consider your extreme hypothetical case: even if the system did get to be in this odd state, that energy would get distributed amongst many degrees of freedom and in short order it would be effectively impossible to tell what the state looked like that you started in.